# What root certificates does Adobe Flash trust?

Tags: flash, https, ssh, adobe

I'm using URLLoader to do a web request via HTTPS, and I need to know what signing authorities Flash trusts.

I've determined that I can't self sign the key, but can't find any documentation from Adobe on who is a trusted signing authority.  Does Flash use the browser's trusted authorities?  If you're using AIR, what list does it use?  Does it vary by platform?

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that flash when run in a browser its the browser who makes all the requests and ultimately decides on those things. But when its run in the air runtime i have no idea.

[Here is a list](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ff0.html) of authorities you can use to sign you air file, Id say its a safe bet that they can be used to secure a https connection running in air to.